# Explicit constant for Carbery–Wright inequality

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, measure-concentration, gaussian

The Carbery–Wright inequality is a seminal result about the anti-concentration of polynomials of Gaussian random variables.
See e.g. [Meka, Nguyen, and Vu - Anti-concentration for polynomials of independent random variables](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.00829), Theorem 1.4, for the precise statement.
However, I cannot find any reference where an explicit estimate on the constant $B$ on the r.h.s. of the inequality is given. Knowing this constant is crucial for the application I have in mind. Are there known estimates on it?
I should also say that the polynomial I have in mind is of the form
$p(g_1,g_2,\dotsc,g_k)=\langle g_1\otimes g_2 \dotsb\otimes g_k,A  g_1\otimes g_2 \dotsb\otimes g_k\rangle$, where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{d^k\times d^k}$, $\operatorname{tr}(A)=0$, and the $g_i\in \mathbb{R}^d$ are random vectors with i.i.d. gaussian entries. Maybe this special structure helps to obtain better anti-concentration estimates.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the original paper by A. Carbery and J. Wright, [Distributional and $L^q$ norm inequalities for polynomials over convex bodies in $\mathbb R^n$](https://doi.org/10.4310/MRL.2001.v8.n3.a1)? Theorem 8 page 244 is the famous inequality with a sharp constant.

Comment: what do you mean by sharp constant? I do not see an explicit constant in that Theorem. You mean this article: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e997/358a17bdd75bd7ffe7126693da12baea325b.pdf ,right?
It only says "There exists an absolute constant C". Do we know what that constant is?

Comment: The way it is stated suggests that C is independent of the polynomial. The constant C is numerical.

Comment: Oh, now I understand the issue. Sure, the constant C is numerical, but my application requires bounding this constant. 
Note that the statement of the inequality only becomes nontrivial for $\alpha\leq C^{-2d}$, where $d$ is the degree of the polynomial. In the application I have in mind, the degree of the polynomial grows, so the inequality is nontrivial only for exponentially small $\alpha$, with the exponent depending on $C$. That is why I actually want to know $C$ in the inequality.

Comment: Then, I guess you should be able to verify its order of magnitude numerically by testing different polynomials in dimension 1 for the Gaussian since it does not depend on the dimension, neither on the degree, neither on the polynomial neither on the measure...

Comment: I am not sure this is correct. The statement only tells us that there is a universal lower bound. But there is no guarantee that polynomials in dimension 1 are "representative". I.e., it could be the case that a much better constant $C$ holds for dimension $1$ compared to, say 59. Of course, this gives a lower bound on the constant, but not a universal upper bound.

Comment: Ok! I thought you were interested in a non-trivial lower bound.